# In the phrase "my dog wiggles it's butt" is the use of the apostrophe correct?

Tags: grammaticality

In the phrase "My dog wiggles it's butt" there seems to be a division of opinion as to whether the use of the apostrophe is grammatically correct.

I suggest that as the *dog* in question is the owner of the *butt* in question and that said *dog* is an animate object replaced by the use of the word *it* then the apostrophe is a correct. Just as we use the apostrophe to show possession in the phrase "Mary's head."

Comment: Lee, please include your research with your question so our users know where you've looked already to try and answer the question.

Comment: It's definitely NOT correct.  *Its* is the correct possessive of *it*, whilst it's means *it is*. I realise it is paradoxical, but it has been the convention for a very long time on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: @WS2 it's not exactly paradoxical, since it follows the usage for _hers_ and _theirs_  (and _ours_...), although there might now be some confusion starting over those examples. You don't often see _hi's_ though.

Comment: The best way to explain how to choose between _its_ and _it's_ is to use random choice; this is the national norm. Since this distinction serves no purpose whatsoever (spoken English doesn't make this distinction, and we never miss it in speech, because it isn't there -- apostrophes are entirely silent), unless someone is paying you to do it their way, do it your own way. Also do it the official way if you're looking for a job and you think your prospective employer may be an ignorant jerk. But for no other reason. Who needs extra morphology just for show?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

It's = it is.

Its = possessive of *it*.

In your sentence, you mean the tail of the dog, so you use *its*. "It is" would not make sense in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Not in this century, it isn't.

> Just as we use the apostrophe to show possession in the phrase "Mary's head."

There are some pronouns that use the apostrophe for possession:

> one's, everyone's, nobody's

But we do not do so with the personal pronouns. The following would all be considered incorrect as possessives:

> *me's, *us's, *you's, *him's, *her's, *it's, *them's

Instead each of these have their own possessive pronoun that can be used independently:

> mine, ours, yours, his, hers, its, theirs.

And that can be used with a noun:

> my, our, your, his, her, its, their.

(Note that *his* and *its* are in both sets).

Historically we would once have found cases of *her's*, *it's* and *their's* here ("Their's not to reason why, Their's not to make reply, Their's but to do and die.") but that was for a brief period in the 19th century and wasn't that common even then. Such cases are long gone.

The only use of *it's* now generally considered is as a contraction of "it is".

So if you find the cases where Alfred, Lord Tennyson or Abraham Lincoln made use of it such apostrophes, they weren't incorrect, but unless an excitable chap turns up in a materialising police box and asks if you'd want to go on an adventure you shouldn't do so yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No! Saying *my dog wiggles **it's** butt* is pretty much saying *my dog wiggles **it is** butt* which, logically, makes no sense.

Whereas, if you use "its" (without the apostrophe) you are using a possessive:

> My dog wiggles **its** butt.

Of which the best translation would probably be *my dog wiggles the butt belonging to itself*.

**Summary:** "it's" = contraction of "it is"; "its" = possessive (of it/belonging to it)